# How to check if an APK contains native code?

Tags: applications, apk

Is there a way to check if an APK file hosts native code?

There are many reverse engineering tools (e.g. [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/), [androguard](http://code.google.com/p/androguard/)) from which you can reproduce the
source files of an Android app but I'm not sure if there is a *de facto* solution
which you can use to assure that an APK contains native code. Maybe someone can
search for ARM binary files in the source files of an app. But how to know which
directories to check?

Is there a more standard way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028134/is-it-possible-to-get-android-mk-or-native-source-file-from-apk-file) should point you in the right direction:

> All of the native code for an app is stored in the libs/ directory in the root of the apk. It's compiled ARM or x86 code, or both. You can find it in libs/architecture_type/lib_name.so. You can dissemble the code with objdump or gdb. Decompiling is a much harder task, but you can find some software that might work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try to make a script that searches for executables in `/libs` directory.

Answer (score 1):

An APK is also an archive so unarchive it on a computer (with tools like [7-Zip](http://7-zip.org)) and look at its content.